# How to setup home page without requiring auth (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to setup a standard homepage that every user has access to (and lands on), before they are routed to other pages after logging in.

Currently the `web.php` setup is

```
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;    
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'home']->withoutMiddleware(['auth']));
```

The `withoutMiddleware` is to try and bypass the requirement of auth when trying to access the `home.blade.php` page, however I get the following error:

[image: error message]

Very new to Laravel, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Put it to the public folder. No route in web.php is needed for public pages. If you want to redirect users after authenticating you should change redirect path in login controller.

Comment: Hey @MartinAmu, are you saying that I should put the home.blade.php file inside the public folder?

Comment: I say that you can put home.php or home.html to the public folder. Address will be yoururl/home.php

Comment: Yeah but I don't want this to be a /(example) link I want the home.blade.php to be the landing page i.e. www.example.com page

Comment: Your routes should all be publically accessible (no authentication required) unless you have explicitly said otherwise elsewhere (such as wrapping your routes in a group).

Comment: Wouldn't that be the `welcome.blade.php` view that comes with Laravel, that should be publicly available already

Answer (score 2):

Routes don't require authentication unless it's explicitly specified in the routes `web.php` file or the controller.

So it can be as following:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;    
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'home'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if(Auth::guest()){
        return view('/home');
    }else{
        return redirect('/login');
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.